# JasperReports stored oracle function java iReport

Tags: oracle, cursor, jasper-reports, ireport, stored-functions

I want to use stored function into JasperReports.

I followed this article for Stored Procedures http://rajendratambat.blogspot.com/2011/10/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-in.html

But how to do similarly for Stored Functions. For Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST_REPORTER
AS

FUNCTION EmpDept(
EMP_ID IN SCOTT.EMP.EMPNO%TYPE)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

OPEN CUR FOR 
SELECT 
EMP.EMPNO AS "EMPLOYEE_ID", 
EMP.ENAME AS "NAME", 
DEPT.DNAME AS "DEPARTMENT" 
FROM 
SCOTT.EMP EMP, SCOTT.DEPT DEPT 
WHERE EMP.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO 
AND EMP.EMPNO = EMP_ID;

RETURN CUR;
END EmpDept;

END PKG_TEST_REPORTER;
```

I tried using this in iReport Designer:

```
{ $P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR} = call pkg_test_reporter.empdept(7782)}
```

But it does not work. Any ideas please?